# Deploy Flask with Gevent or Tornado on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, gevent, pythonanywhere

I wanted to make my flask app on pythonanywhere asynchronous, and for that I was thinking of using either Gevent or Tornado to do so.  But was unable to find any clear information on how to do this.

Trying to make it use Gevent, I edited my WSGI config file (no, I didn't know what I was doing) and changed this line:

```
from flask_app import app as application
```

...to this:

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from flask_app import app
application = WSGIServer(("", 5000), app)
```

As I anticipated, it did not work.  What is the correct way to do this?  And if it is a better option, what would I do to deploy my app with Tornado?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?  Was there an error, or did you benchmark it and not see any improvements?

Comment: There was an error.  Something about WSGIServer not being callable.

Comment: [`WSGIServer`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.wsgi.html) is indeed not callable - what are you trying to do, run `gevent` in a WSGI container?  If so, what is your container? (Apache, nginx, uwsgi ... ?)

Comment: PythonAnywhere uses uWSGI for it, but one of their staff said that asynchronous apps don't work with uWSGI, or don't work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using uwsgi it [comes with support for gevent](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Gevent.html) built in - but you won't be hooking into it by using `WSGIServer` - instead, uwsgi will hook into the event loop for you and you can just use `spawn`, `join`, etc. in your application code and everything should just work. (Assuming that uwsgi was started with the right parameters).

Comment: Well, that depends on how PythonAnywhere has it set up.